# I cant fill the recyclerview in fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am getting data from **ActivityA** and trying to access **fragment** method for fill **RecyclerView**.

Set up **TabLayout** Method in **Activity**;

```
private void setTabLayout(String key, String content) {
    //Create Fragment
    SearchPostFragment fragment = new SearchPostFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", key);
    bundle.putString("content", content);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    //init
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.search_activity_tab);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.search_activity_container);
    adapter = new SettingsViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    //Add Fragments
    adapter.addFragment(fragment, getString(R.string.activity_search_tablayout_post_title));
    adapter.addFragment(new SearchUserFragment(), getString(R.string.activity_search_tablayout_user_title));
    //Setup Adapter
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Im using this **Set Up TabLayout** method on my **Activity onCreate()** to set up, firstly giving null;

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        setTabLayout(null, null);
    }
```

And then Im calling **fragment** method from **EditText key listener**;

```
    searchET.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                //Pressed Enter
                String searchText = searchET.getText().toString();
                if (!searchText.trim().equals("")){
                    switch (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()){
                        case 0: //Post
                            SearchPostFragment fragment = new SearchPostFragment();
                            fragment.searchPost(key, content);
                            break;
                        case 1: //User

                            break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The **Fragment** method looks like;

```
public void searchPost(String key, String content) {
        Call<SearchResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getSearch(key, content);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SearchResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SearchResponse> call, Response<SearchResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (!response.body().isError()) {
                        searchList = response.body().getSearch();
                        adapter = new SearchPostAdapter(getActivity(), searchList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

And im getting;

```
onResponse: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

But if i call that **method** in my **fragment** like in **onViewCreated** everything going well.
I tried send **context** or get context in **onAttach** but these didnt work

Im using **Tab Layout** structure btw.

My App looks like [https://i.ibb.co/mCy6PS8/photo5951987656600695037.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz672.jpg)

I can give you more information if you needed

I solved the problem with this;

**EditText OnKeyListener**

```
Fragment searchPostFragment = (SearchPostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
((SearchPostFragment) searchPostFragment).searchPost(key, content);
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: recyclerView object is null that's why exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because the fragment view is not inflated yet. You should consider passing those data through arguments.

**In your Activity**:

```java
SearchPostFragment fragment = new SearchPostFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", key);
bundle.putString("content", content);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
// then do the fragment transaction
```

**SearchFragment.java**

```java
public class SearchPostFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        // replace fragment_layout with your fragment view
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        // replace recycler_view with your view id

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            String key = args.getString("key");
            String content = args.getString("content");
            if (key != null && content != null) {
                makeApiCall(key, content);
            }
        }
    }

    void makeApiCall(String key, String content) {
        Call<SearchResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getSearch(key, content);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SearchResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SearchResponse> call, Response<SearchResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (!response.body().isError()) {
                        searchList = response.body().getSearch();
                        adapter = new SearchPostAdapter(getActivity(), searchList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my activity and fragment: https://i.ibb.co/mCy6PS8/photo5951987656600695037.jpg
Im doing transaction on activity's onCreate method
so i just want to type something on the input and then call 'makeApiCall for see the result'
i tried your codes but i couldnt do anything

Comment: how did you call the `makeApiCall` method? Could please add that code to the question as well?

Comment: Im calling the method from EditText's onKeyListener if it is whats your needed and i added to question

Comment: You need to inflate your fragment layout first before using any of the views.

Comment: I updated my question too. Im doing what exactly you said to me and if i calling **setTabLayout(String key, String content)** method with values its working but i want to trigger it with **EditText onKeyListener()**

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the instance method for the fragment.

```
    public static SearchPostFragment  newInstance(String key,String content) {
    SearchPostFragment searchFragment = new SearchPostFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key_1", key);
    args.putString("key_2", content);
    searchFragment.setArguments(args);
    return searchFragment;

}
```

In OnCreate method of the fragment call method like below.

```
OnCreate(){

   //Write those things below of your recycler view initialization

    String key  = getArguments().getInt("key_1","");
    String content  = getArguments().getInt("key_2", "");
    searchPost(key, content);


}
```

Call fragment from an activity like that:-

SearchPostFragment.newInstance(key,content);

Answer (score 0):

**Issue With Your Recycler View** it is common Problem Occur when you call static method from other class for that best solution is that **you can implement interface.** Or

You can try to initialize recycler view inside your retrofit response.

```
         try {
```

> ```
>                 recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
>                 layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
>                 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
> ```

```
                if (!response.body().isError()) {
                    searchList = response.body().getSearch();
                    adapter = new SearchPostAdapter(getActivity(), searchList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but i cant get view in this method.